# MUC File transferring in openfire

Tags: openfire, multiuserchat

I have implemented MUC in openfire in which I am working on file sharing thing which is not working in my case. When I use:

```
FullJID = JidCreate.entityFullFrom("groupname@conference.domain name/resource name") for transferring file it is not working and
```

When I use:

```
FullJID = JidCreate.entityFullFrom(group+"@conference."+Constant.DOMAIN_NAME+"/"+group+Receiver+"@conference."+Constant.DOMAIN_NAME+"/"+Constant.RESOURCE)
```

It is working fine but in that case I have to send file separately to each member of the group.

Is there any permanent solution in which we send file in group on single hit?

Comment: This is usefull for you https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-preferable-way-to-for-sending-file-image-video-with-xmpp-stanza